# Callback function not found while it is defined above

Tags: php, arrays, callback

I have this code snippet that is supposed to find the differences between two arrays of feed items:

```
protected function execute()
{
    $existingFeedItems = $feed->getItems();
    $newFeedItems = $feed->loadItems();

    function compareFeedItemIds($feedItem1, $feedItem2)
    {
        return $feedItem1->getFeedItemId() == $feedItem2->getFeedItemId() ? 0 : -1;
    }

    $feedItemsAdded = array_udiff($newFeedItems, $existingFeedItems, "compareFeedItemIds");
    $feedItemsRemoved = array_udiff($existingFeedItems, $newFeedItems, "compareFeedItemIds");
    $unchangedFeedItems = array_uintersect($newFeedItems, $existingFeedItems, "compareFeedItemIds");
}
```

This will throw the error:

> Warning: array_udiff() expects parameter 3 to be a valid callback,
>   function 'compareFeedItemIds' not found or invalid function name

Even though I have defined that function above. What is the reason for PHP throwing this error? I have to add I am executing this from an object's method context.

Comment: If this callback is defined inside the class, then the callback should be `[$this, "compareFeedItemIds"]`? Otherwise you're trying to access a global function. [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Comment: try 'compareFeedItemIds' instead of "compareFeedItemIds"

Comment: If its inside a class method then it would be quite a good idea to show the example _in the same condition as it really exists_ *Its quite relevant if you think about it!*

Comment: @MarkBaker This changed the error into class "xxx" does not have a method, because it tries to execute the object's function, but it is not defined as an object function, but as a scope function.

Comment: @MukeshRam This did not change anything, as it will stay a regular string.

Comment: If you're nesting the function definition inside the method definition, then it's creating it as a global scope function when you call the method..... contrary to popular belief, there is no such thing as a sub-function in PHP, and it really isn't good practise

Comment: Are you namespacing your class?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, it's in a namespace.

Comment: If your callback is in that same namespace, then you need to indicate this `$feedItemsAdded = array_udiff($newFeedItems, $existingFeedItems, "namespace\\compareFeedItemIds");`

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes that's the solution, could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your callback function is defined within a namespace, then you need to indicate that namespace when you make the `udiff()` call.

```
$feedItemsAdded = array_udiff($newFeedItems, $existingFeedItems, "namespace\\compareFeedItemIds");
```

Otherwise PHP will search for the callback function in the global namespace

Comment: Thanks, and next time I will provide the full (simplified) file, to prevent all the guessing as to what situation I'm in.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume having a local function definition and/or lambda function really is a good idea (it get's way less attractive if you have the same function definiton a couple of times scattered over your project ....).
You *can* define a function within another function/method and this defintion only takes place when execution of the script(s) reaches this code. But: The function definition isn't local; it bubbles up - outside of the function/class. And because of that you will get a "cannot redeclare function compareFeedItemIds" error if you execute `execute()` more than once.
There are several options to "fix" that.
You can assign the function to a local variable and then pass that variable as the third parameter to the array_* functions.

```
$compareFeedItemIds = function($feedItem1, $feedItem2) {
    return $feedItem1->getFeedItemId() == $feedItem2->getFeedItemId() ? 0 : -1;
};

$feedItemsAdded = array_udiff($newFeedItems, $existingFeedItems, $compareFeedItemIds);
$feedItemsRemoved = array_diff($existingFeedItems, $newFeedItems, $compareFeedItemIds);
....
```

You can also store that function in an instance variable ...or a static class member.

Or... to avoid the namspace problem, just create a static method in your class and then reference that method via self::methodname or [static::methodname](http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.late-static-bindings) like e.g.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        $a = [1,2,3];
        $b = [2,3,4];

         var_export( array_udiff($a, $b, 'self::moo') );
         var_export( array_udiff($b, $a, 'self::moo') );
         var_export( array_uintersect($a, $b, 'self::moo') );
    }

    protected static function moo($a,$b) {
        return $a<=>$b;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar();
```